# How to populate Jenkins build parameter values from URL in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

How can I populate choice parameter from the URL?
I'm able to download and save values inside environment variable but if I try to use it I get error:
if I replace choicesFoo with choicesURL in parameters section, I get error.

Here is my pipeline:

```
def choicesFoo = ['x','y']

pipeline{
    agent { 
        node { 
            label 'LinuxOpt'
        } 
    }
    environment{
        choicesUrl = sh(script: "curl http://example.com/foo.txt", returnStdout: true)
    }
     parameters {
        choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: choicesFoo, description: 'Pick an option')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo run build'
                 sh "echo ${choicesUrl}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the full `parameters` class to provide dynamic choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try preparing your `choices` before declaring a pipeline, e.g. like this:

```
def choicesUrl 

node('Prepare Choices') {
    stage('Get Choices') {
        choicesUrl = sh(
            script: "curl http://example.com/foo.txt", 
            returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
}


pipeline{
    agent { node { label 'LinuxOpt' } }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: choicesUrl, description: 'Pick an option')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo run build'
                sh "echo ${choicesUrl}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```